# Convert the currency format to USD for the purchases outside India

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, countries

I have set up my magento store with magento 1.9. I want the currency format to be automatically converted to USD throughout my magento store, if the customer is purchasing from any country other than India. Can anyone kindly tell me how I can do this?

Edit: The answer given by Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd. below worked out for me I am also posting an answer with a function to find IP too. So the whole function would work available for those who search for the same. Find the whole answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the answer posted by Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd. I have included the method to find IP too. find it below.

```
function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$country = ip_info("Visitor", "Country Code");

    if($country!="IN")
    {
       Mage::app();
       Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD');
       Mage::reset();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing some customization in `index.php` file you can set default currency before `Mage::run()` for that you have to add this code before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

```
    $country="Your logic to get country code";
    if($country!="IN")
    {
       Mage::app();
       Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD');
       Mage::reset();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Geo IP MAGENTO STORE SWITCHER BASED ON CUSTOMER LOCATION.

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.atwix.com/magento/geoip-magento-store-switcher/) , you can find complete code [here](https://github.com/vovsky/Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher)

I am posting code, just if link become 404 page

```
/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Helper/Data.php */
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const DEFAULT_STORE = 'English';

    /**
     * countries to store relation
     * default is English
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_countryToStore = array(
        'US' => 'English',
        'UK' => 'English'

    );

    /**
     * get store view name by country
     * @param $country
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getStoreByCountry($country)
    {
        if (isset($this->_countryToStore[$country])) {
            return $this->_countryToStore[$country];
        }
        return self::DEFAULT_STORE;
    }
}

<!--app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/etc/config.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>       
<config>
 ...
    <global>
    ...
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers>
                    <atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                        <class>atwix_ipstoreswitcher/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPostdispatch</method>
                    </atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>

/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Model/Observer.php */

class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {
        $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
        if ($cookie->get('geoip_processed') != 1) {
            $geoIPCountry = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
            $countryCode = $geoIPCountry->getCountry();
            if ($countryCode) {
                $storeName = Mage::helper('atwix_ipstoreswitcher')->getStoreByCountry($countryCode);
                if ($storeName) {
                    $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeName, 'name');
                    if ($store->getName() != Mage::app()->getStore()->getName()) {
                        $event->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($store->getCurrentUrl(false));
                    }
                }
            }
            $cookie->set('geoip_processed', '1', time() + 86400, '/');
        }
    }
}
```